# Why Isn't My FileOutputstream Writing to a File?

Tags: java, android

I'm a beginner working on an Android app that uses the gcacace SignaturePad library to capture the signature of my user.  My goal is to take the signature, compress it down into a JPEG, and then write that information to a file on the users phone so the picture can be accessed later.

I am currently getting no errors or crashes when I run the code, yet no directory or file is being created when I test the app out on my device(Google Pixel 2).  Can anyone give me a hand figuring out where the problem is?  I've thrown my head against a wall this entire morning and still don't know.

```
ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
            File directory = cw.getDir("images", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            if (!directory.exists()) {
                directory.mkdirs();
            }
            File myPath = new File(directory, "1.jpg");

            FileOutputStream fOut = null;

            try {
                fOut = new FileOutputStream(myPath);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            signaturePad.getSignatureBitmap().compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fOut);
            Bitmap signature = signaturePad.getSignatureBitmap();

            int bytes = signature.getByteCount();

            try {
                fOut.write(bytes);
                fOut.flush();
                fOut.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            Toast.makeText(activity_signature_pad.this, "Signature Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: "yet no directory or file is being created" -- how are you looking for it? You are storing it in [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/06/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), so you would need Android Studio's Device File Explorer or `adb shell` to look for the results. Note that you do not need the `ContextWrapper`.

Comment: I was under the belief that this method would create a folder in my Android -> App Specific folder(i.e com.appname.whatever) so that's where I've been checking.  How would I go about specifying that location?

Comment: I am going to assume that you are referring to your app-specific directory on [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html). If so, change `File directory = cw.getDir("images", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)` to `File directory = getExternalFilesDir(null)` or possibly `File directory = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "images")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in your question writes to what the Android SDK refers to [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/06/storage-situation-internal-storage.html). That is private to your app; ordinary users do not have access to it (including you, except when using developer tools).

You appear to want to write to [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html). For that, use:

```
File directory = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "images")
```